# How to set the default python for new created conda enviroment?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed anaconda and the base environment is using the anaconda python:

Command `type python` returns `/home/ya/anaconda3/bin/python`.
However, when I create a new environment, the default python under the new environment is the `/usr/bin/python`. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

The information below is also covered in [the documentation on creating environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands).

### New Environments are Empty

**Conda is a general package and environment manager**, not a Python-specific one. Hence, when creating a new environment it does not assume that one wants Python. Instead, if one wants Python installed, it must be specified, e.g.,

```bash
conda create -n foo python
```

Note that the `create` command can also take version constraints, as well as additional packages. It is best to specify all packages one expects *at the time of creation* as this simplifies the solving.

---

### Default Packages

The `create_default_packages` configuration option is available to specify a default set of packages that will always be installed at creation to time. For example, if you know that you will always want Python installed, one could use:

```bash
conda config --add create_default_packages python
```

Note that version can be specified here as well. All subsequent environment creations will then install Python.

One can also subsequently override such defaults with the flag `--no-default-packages`.